# How to use x-systemd-makefs to make a filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, systemd

I'm trying to make systemd make an ext4 filesystem on a disk (/dev/xvdh).

The manual is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-makefs@.service.html

I don't understand how to use it. It says to use `systemd-makefs@device.service` but I don't know what that means.

I've tried:

```
root@ip-10-00:~# systemctl enable systemd-makefs@/dev/xvdh.service
Failed to look up unit file state: Invalid argument
root@ip-10-00:~# systemctl enable systemd-makefs@\/dev\/xvdh.service
Failed to look up unit file state: Invalid argument
root@ip-10-00:~# systemctl enable systemd-makefs@.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file systemd-makefs@.service does not exist.
root@ip-10-00:~# systemctl enable systemd-makefs@xvdh.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file systemd-makefs@xvdh.service does not exist.
```

I've also tried this line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/xvdh       /data     ext4    x-systemd.makefs    0       2
```

Nothing seems to work. I haven't been able to find any examples of how this is used in practice.

Does anybody know how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, only a reboot was required to make it work. What worked was the fstab line:

```
/dev/xvdh       /data     ext4    x-systemd.makefs    0       2
```

But it only worked after a reboot, probably because the mount stage is only run then.

Answer (score 1):

This service unit doesn't have a template. Each instance is individually generated by *systemd-fstab-generator* based on your fstab contents – not just the device name but also the filesystem type.

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reapply all generators.